# Implementing Pass-Through with Grails Filters

Tags: redirect, grails, grails-filters

**Please note:** Although I'm using the [Grails Webflow](https://grails.org/plugin/webflow) plugin here, I am pretty sure this is just a generic question that any battle-weary Grails veteran could answer.

---

Grails 2.4.4 here. I have a need for a [Grails Filter](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/ref/Plug-ins/filters.html) that inspects all traffic coming into a particular controller. If the app is in a particular state, I need to redirect traffic to another controller/action. Else, I need the filter to act as a no-op/pass-through filter (meaning it does nothing; just allows the request to pass through it and on to its intended destination):

```
package filters

class MyAppFilters {
    def filters = {
        fizzFilter(controller: 'fizz', action: '*') {
            before = {
                if(AppStateHolder.checkState() == AppState.Blue) {
                    redirect(controller: 'auth', action: 'unauthorized')
                    return false
                } else {
                    // Allow request to continue on to its intended controller/action target ('no-op'/pass-through)
                    ???
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have everything working perfectly for when the app state is `AppState.Blue` (so, the `if`-condition). **The problem is that when app state isn't "blue", and that `else` executes, I keep getting infinite redirect errors.** I believe Grails Webflow is complicating things, but I can't really fix anything with how it has been implemented.

I've also tried returning `true`/`false` from inside the `else` like so:

```
} else {
    // Allow request to continue on to its intended controller/action target ('no-op'/pass-through)
    return false // Also tried 'true'
}
```

But this produces the same infinite redirect errors. It looks like I need to do some kind of `redirect`/`render`/etc. inside this `else` or webflow will cause problems.

So I'm looking for a way to tell Grails to redirect to whatever was the controller/action off the request. Something like:

```
} else {
    // Allow request to continue on to its intended controller/action target ('no-op'/pass-through)
    redirect(controller: req.controller, action: req.action)
    return false
}
```

Is this possible, if so, how (specifically)?

Comment: try with grail clean-all ;)

Comment: Thanks @SandeepPoonia (+1) - however this does not work (nor do I see why it would!)

Comment: This is a grails magic wand that does some magic whenever your application behaves in a way it shouldn't.